# Java self-typed methods: cannot safely cast to actual type

Tags: java, generics, self-type

Consider the following class, which I believe is correctly called a [self-typed](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=136394) class:

```
public abstract class Example<E extends Example<E>> {
  /** Constructs an instance of the subclass */
  protected abstract E construct();

  /** Do a private operation in the base class */
  private void specialOp() {}

  public E get1() {
    E obj = construct();
    // Error: The method specialOp() from the type Example<E> is not visible
    obj.specialOp();
    return obj;
  }

  public E get2() {
    Example<E> obj = construct();
    obj.specialOp();
    // Warning: Type safety: Unchecked cast from Example<E> to E
    return (E)obj;
  }

  public E get3() {
    E obj = construct();
    ((Example<E>)obj).specialOp();
    return obj;
  }
}
```

That is to say, implementations extending this class would have a type signature like so:

```
public class SubExample extends Example<SubExample>
```

Each of the three `get*()` methods ostensibly do the same thing - construct a subclass of `Example`, execute a private method on the instance, and return it as its subtype.  However only the last example compiles without warnings.

The behavior in `get1()` is an error even without generics, consider:

```
public class Example {
  private void specialOp() {};

  public void get(SubExample e) {
    // Error: The method specialOp() from the type Example is not visible
    e.specialOp();
  }

  public static class SubExample extends Example {}
}
```

Which I understand, even if it seems unnecessarily restrictive to me.  And similarly `get3()` makes sense, though I dislike needing to cast like that.  But `get2()` confuses me.  I understand `E` is technically a subtype of `Example<E>`, but don't the bounds of this generic ensure that all `Example<E>`s are also `E`s?  If so, why is it not safe to cast like this?  Is it ever possible to cast from `Example<E>` to `E` without a warning?

Comment: Is it possible to cast `List<Integer>` to `Integer` ?

Comment: make the `specialOp` method protected instead of private.

Comment: @alfasin since `E extends Example<E>` yes, it is *possible* to cast an `Example<E>` to an `E`.  The self-type type signature is intended to guarantee that for all `E`, but I'm not certain if that's true.

Comment: @Henry thank you, yes, that would resolve the compilation issue.  However that isn't my question.

Comment: @dimo414 you're right - didn't notice that first line :) Since `E extends Example<E>` and you're down-casting `Example<E>` to `E` you get the warning. Why would you expect `Example<E>` to be of type `E` ?

Comment: @alfasin That's the idea of using this type of generic signature - "the type parameter must be the same as the class being defined".  I added a reference in the question text.  This is, for instance, how `Enum` classes are defined.

Comment: The answer you've accepted says the same thing as my previous comment...

Comment: The answer I accepted provided a counter example and demonstrated that the quote "must be the same" was incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all `Example<E>`s must be `E`s:

```
public class A extends Example<A> { ... }
public class B extends Example<A> { ... }

Example<A> notAnA = new B();
```

So the compiler is correct.

Note that `get3()` can also be written:

```
public E get3() {
    E obj = construct();
    Example<E> objAsEx = obj;
    objAsEx.specialOp();
    return obj;
}
```

So the compiler knows that code is correct, even without an explicit cast. It doesn't seem to apply this knowledge to allow the private member access without having it's hand held, though.

Comment: Well there you go! Thanks, in hind-sight that's a very obvious counter-example. I know Java's support for self-type generics is limited at best, but is it possible to construct a more restrictive generic type that does actually enforce self-typing?

Comment: @dimo414: No, it's not possible. That's why declarations like `class Example<E extends Example<E>>` are useless for what people use it for; `class Example<E>` works just as well.

Comment: @newacct that's not quite right - the former still provides a guarantee that it's a sublcass of `Example<E>` - without that my `get3()` wouldn't compile.

Comment: @dimo414: But that's a contrived example that is rarely encountered by people trying to use such a bound