# Why does ArrayList have a clone method

Tags: java, arraylist

I am not sure I understand the purpose of `clone()` in `ArrayList`.

there are many ways to make a shallow copy of an `ArrayList`, I know at least two:

```
List<Integer> L1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
List<Integer> L1_copy = new ArrayList<>(L1);
List<Integer> L1_copy2 = List.copyOf(L1);   // inmutable but solve by below:
List<Integer> L1_copy3 = new ArrayList<>(List.copyOf(L1));
```

It is also surprising that this returns an `Object`, instead of an `ArrayList`, And I have to downcast:

```
ArrayList<Integer> AL1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
ArrayList<Integer> AL1_copy = (ArrayList<Integer>) AL1.clone();
```

Why is it designed to be returning as an `Object`?
Any advantage of using the clone over other shallow copy method?

Comment: It is implementing the [`Cloneable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) interface, which at one point someone must have thought was a good idea. It's not a very useful interface.

Comment: that is interesting, are there objects that are not cloneable?

Comment: Of course. Lots of classes do not implement Cloneable.

Comment: this method if from `Object` class. See javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()

Comment: If you want to see exactly how they implement cloneable in Arraylist, here is the source for Arraylist for Java8
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l328
It seems to just call Arrays.copyOf on the backend. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(U[],%20int,%20java.lang.Class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typing is a result of ArrayList being written before java 5.  Before java 5, the return type of an overriding method had to be the same as the method which was being overridden (was *invariant*).  Today, since method return types can be specialized (are *covariant*), if ArrayList were being rewritten, it should be written with ArrayList as the return type.

However, there is a deep problem here, which is that while an implementation can specialize clone()'s return type, the type system hasn't expressed the typing relationship fully.  What would be better would be a "self" type, which java only marginally supports.  That gets you pretty deep into typing theory.  See, for example: [Java self-typed methods: cannot safely cast to actual type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115354/java-self-typed-methods-cannot-safely-cast-to-actual-type).

From a utility perspective, as others have said, Cloneable has turned out to not be a very useful API.  In practice, there tend to be too many particulars to how one wants copy to work for a single API to fit all of those particulars.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an added advantage because of the presence of the `clone()` method. In the case of primitives, it would equate to a deep copy.
Also, I did not know these many methods in Java except the constructor one, in which you pass the `Collection` as an argument in the constructor.
It also implements the `Cloneable` interface which I think is like a marker interface.
It returns `Object` because it is the superclass of all classes and returning it would not break the code.

Comment: Though it is declared in `Object`, the one in `Object` is protected. ArrayList exposes the method publicly and provides its own implementation, which works because the class implements `Cloneable`.

Comment: even if it did not override it, it would still be available.

Comment: If it did not override it, the method would be protected, so *not* publicly available.

Comment: hmm. thanks. I will edit the answer. I forgot this detail.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a public clone() method supports polymorphism. You can call it on a reference of a superclass type, to clone an object of any subclass type.

> Why is it designed to be returning as an Object?

Covariant return types were introduced in Java 5. `ArrayList` was introduced earlier, in Java 2.

`ArrayList` is not a final class. Modifying its return type to return ArrayList could have broken third-party subclasses.

> Any advantage of using the clone over other shallow copy method?

Polymorphism.